# CGKeyEvent Pasting working with Breakpoints, but not without

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, breakpoints

I have searched on StackOverflow a lot about this topic. And what I have found so far was of great use. But now, I came to a very interesting fact.

In my case, I hide the app via `NSApp hide:self`

I then add a character to the pasteboard, and then try to input it in the frontmost application via CGEvents. My Code for this is as follows:

```
-(void)applicationDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification{
    stringToInsert = @"©";

    NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pasteboard clearContents];
    NSArray *copiedObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObject:stringToInsert];
    [pasteboard writeObjects:copiedObjects];

    //Use CGEvents to "press" Cmd-V
    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
    CGEventRef pasteCommandDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)9, YES);
    CGEventSetFlags(pasteCommandDown, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
    CGEventRef pasteCommandUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)9, NO);

    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, pasteCommandDown);
    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, pasteCommandUp);

    CFRelease(pasteCommandUp);
    CFRelease(pasteCommandDown);
    CFRelease(source);

}
```

My **problem** is that it doesn't want to insert text when I'm running it from within XCode **without** breaktpoints. It rather makes the mac's characteristic "plong" if he's uncapable os something.

But **if** I set a breakpoint to the method itself, and then jump by line, it curiously inserts it at instant.

Sorry for my bad English and for my perhaps bad text formatting as I'm new here on stackoverflow.

If you could help, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before, and my guess is that the events are getting posted too quickly for the system to handle (since it really only has to handle no more than, say, 20 key events a second).  I'd guess that putting in something like `usleep(100000)` (pause the thread for 1/10 of a second) would help quite significantly.

Comment: Thank you! Sadly, it doesn't solve the problem directly, but gladly, it helps to determine the problem. I specified a rather long amount of time, one 0 more, so it should be one second. I then tried it, and realized, that the focus didn't **really** pass to the next window. I don't know why, because, as mentioned earlier, if I use a breakpoint, the focus passes to the underlying window. I wonder because the whole codeblock **is** called **when** the application **didHide** so the focus **should have changed**. So how do I get the focus to change and **then** call the code block? Thanks so far!