# NSView only redraws on breakpoint

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a custom view inside a `NSPopover`. It should change according to user input and it does the first time the user interact with it but it fails to redraw the following times.

I have tried to put an `NSLog` inside the `-drawRect:` method and it doesn't get called during normal execution. When I try to debug and put a breakpoint inside the method it gets called normally and the app works as it should.

I explicitly call the view `-setNeedsDisplay:` method every time I need it to redraw.
I don't understand why it should make a difference.

Here is the code that update the status of the view. These methods are part of the `NSTextField` delegate method `-textDidChange:` and I checked that these get called every time the user type something in the textfield associated with popover.

```
[tokenCloud tokensToHighlight:[NSArray arrayWithObject:completeSuggestionString]];
tokenCloud.tokens = filteredTokens;
[tokenCloud setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

The views is a series of recessed button. The first line update the status of all the buttons in the popover and the second add or delete buttons. They both work properly because the first time they are called the view is update properly. I have also checked that both the status of the buttons in `tokenCloud` and its property `tokens` are updated correctly. The problem is that the `NSView` subclass, `tokenCloud`, doesn't redraw so the changes are not reflected in the UI the second time.

Here is the draw method of the view:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    [self recalculateButtonLocations];
    NSLog(@"Redrawn");
}
```

Again this method gets called normally every time I update the view if I place a breakpoint in `[self recalculateButtonLocations];`. If instead I let the app run normally nothing gets logged in the console the second time I update the view. Same thing if I include the `NSLog` in the `recalculateButtonLocations` method, nothing gets logged the second time meaning that the method is not called.

Comment: can you add a minimal code example which exhibits the problem?

Comment: My apologies. I edited the post and added the code.

Comment: since it's a custom view, try overriding `setNeedsDisplay` as to include a log before calling `super`.

Comment: i can't reproduce the bug - it works fine for me. I assume tokenCloud being the custom view you're putting inside NSPopover, which is also the text field delegate

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2: For future readers, sorry that this answer is of low quality. Most of it is useless and the useful parts should've been made as a comment. I would delete it but I feel that would be disingenuous. Hopefully anyone having this issue can find more insight in the linked answers, which do contain some information on why sometimes adding breakpoints can alter the flow of a program.**

Depending on how you're drawing the buttons, it might be a better idea to use `layoutSubviews` and `setNeedsLayout`, than `drawRect` for repositioning subviews. *[EDIT: Didn't see this was for Mac OS and not iOS. `layout` is indeed equivalent to layoutSubviews and there is a `setNeedsLayout` for `NSView`, where subview arrangement should be done.]*

Can't give any more advice without more information. However, the fact that it works with a breakpoint is curious. I can't see a reason why having a breakpoint on a method call line results in it getting called more often; the method should be called or not, regardless of whether a breakpoint is on it and it seems like this bug cannot be replicated with the above code alone... making me think it's something else in your code causing this problem.

---

Some similar questions to yours regarding breakpoints changing the code flow. Maybe sleep the code/add a pause in some way other than breakpoints and see if it works? If it does it could indicate one of the below problems.

> The number one cause for breakpoints altering how the code works is
>   race conditions. It basically goes like this:
>
> ```
> Without breakpoints:
>     make some asynchronous request
>     do something with response
>     ERROR because request hasn't responded yet
>
> With breakpoints:
>     send some asynchronous request
>     wait for user to continue
>     response arrived while waiting for the continue
>     do something with response
>     OK!
> ```

^Niet the Dark Absol from [Breakpoint changes program flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083526/breakpoint-changes-program-flow)

> I've seen this before, and my guess is that the events are getting
>   posted too quickly for the system to handle (since it really only has
>   to handle no more than, say, 20 key events a second). I'd guess that
>   putting in something like usleep(100000) (pause the thread for 1/10 of
>   a second) would help quite significantly.

^Dave DeLong from [CGKeyEvent Pasting working with Breakpoints, but not without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239140/cgkeyevent-pasting-working-with-breakpoints-but-not-without)

> Generally indicates a race condition; your code is dependent on thread
>   A finishing or not finishing something before thread B hits some
>   particular state.

^bbum from [EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but not when using breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569241/exc-bad-access-but-not-when-using-breakpoints)

Comment: I can't seem to find the `layoutSubviews` method in `NSView`. Did you mean `-layout`. The problem with this is that it seems to apply to constraint based view which is not my case. Anyway I can always try to implement it with constraints. Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately contentMode is not available for `NSViews` in cocoa.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't see a tag for iOS or Mac OS and figured you were developing an iOS application which uses the UI family of classes (UIView has contentMode and layoutSubviews). Sorry about that! xD

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway for taking the time to suggest something.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. It's odd that it works with a breakpoint but not without, though. Some quick searching on stack overflow reveals a few other, similar problems. Maybe try sleeping/adding a pause instead of a breakpoint? I'll add some links to my original post to similar cases.